# Matching suffix of string with case-statement

Tags: bash, switch-statement

How would you match a suffix of a string with a case-statement?

Example

```
case "foobar" in
    "*bar")
        echo "yay!"
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works well if you just lose the quotes;

```
#!/bin/bash
case "foobar" in
    *bar)
        echo "yay!"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: The crucial part is to not quote the wildcard `*` since that will interpolate it literally.  You can still quote other parts if you need to.  `case $foo in *" bar "*' baz '*) echo yay;; esac`